# How to convert a TemplateLiteral AST node back into template string source code?

Tags: javascript, algorithm, abstract-syntax-tree

So I am working through ["normalizing" a JS AST](https://github.com/lancejpollard/normalize-ast.js/blob/040dcbfb584e25f1fb58106956f06e0c899000d9/index.js) in certain ways to make transpilation easier into a particular target language. So I am having to learn the inner details of the AST. Then for testing, I am converting it back into JS source code, using [print functions](https://github.com/lancejpollard/normalize-ast.js/blob/af39cb30471e66a6bd4a3b0d14f6f0072186813d/print.js). I have handled pretty much every case so far, but the `TemplateLiteral` seems like it's a strange structure.

For example, you have this template string:

```
const str = 'const b83 = `foo${a100} bar ${b82}`'
```

Parse that `str` into an AST and you get this structure:

```
{
  "type": "TemplateLiteral",
  "start": 2692,
  "end": 2715,
  "expressions": [
    {
      "type": "Identifier",
      "start": 2698,
      "end": 2702,
      "name": "a100"
    },
    {
      "type": "Identifier",
      "start": 2710,
      "end": 2713,
      "name": "b82"
    }
  ],
  "quasis": [
    {
      "type": "TemplateElement",
      "start": 2693,
      "end": 2696,
      "value": {
        "raw": "foo",
        "cooked": "foo"
      },
      "tail": false
    },
    {
      "type": "TemplateElement",
      "start": 2703,
      "end": 2708,
      "value": {
        "raw": " bar ",
        "cooked": " bar "
      },
      "tail": false
    },
    {
      "type": "TemplateElement",
      "start": 2714,
      "end": 2714,
      "value": {
        "raw": "",
        "cooked": ""
      },
      "tail": true
    }
  ]
}
```

Notice, the "expressions" and "quasis" are not interlaced, they are made into separate arrays. How am I to go back and properly put them in the right order to regenerate the template string source code? Assume this AST node might be part of a larger AST, and the tree might be rewritten, so any information you use regarding the start and end text positions will only be useful from a relative, not absolute, perspective. I am just not quite sure the best way to read the start and end to re-interlace the expressions and quasis.

Comment: To clarify, you want to re-order these into `"foo"` -> `"${a100}"` -> `" bar "` -> `"${b82}"` -> `""`?

Comment: Yes exactly, that's what I want.

Comment: That rather bizarre organization reflects the way that tag functions are called from [tagged templates](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Template_literals#tagged_templates). If you have two consecutive interpolated expressions in the template, you'll find a corresponding empty string in the string array, so the array always has one more element than there are interpolated expressions.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You're always going to have `quasis.length == expressions.length+1`.  You just take the first quasi, then the first expression, then the next quasi, then the next expression, etc., until the last quasi.

Answer (score 0):

```
function getResultFromTemplateLiteral(ret, path) {


    const { expressions, quasis } = ret

    // 拼接模板
    let str = ''
    for (let i = 0; i < quasis.length; i++) {
        if (i) {
            str += '__' + expressions[i - 1].name + '__'
        }
        str += quasis[i].value.cooked
    }

    // 收集变量引用
    const expMap = new Map()

    for (let i = 0; i < expressions.length; i++) {
        const { name } = expressions[i]

        if (!expMap.has(name)) {
            const ref = path.scope.getBinding(name)
            if (ref) {
                let { init, init: { type, value } } = ref.path.node
                if (type === 'StringLiteral') {
                    expMap.set(name, value)
                } else if (type === 'TemplateLiteral') {
                    expMap.set(name, getResultFromTemplateLiteral(init, path))
                }
            } else {
                expMap.set(name, '')
            }
        }
    }

    return str = str.replace(/__(.*?)__/gim, name => expMap.get(name.replace(/__/g, '')))

    
}
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).